# TSQL Is there a way to skip execution of functions in INNER JOIN clause?

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
FUNCTION F1
INNER JOIN TABLE T1
INNER JOIN FUNCTION F2 
INNER JOIN FUNCTION F3
INNER JOIN FUNCTION F4
...
INNER JOIN TABLE T2
```

In some situations when `FUNCTION F1` returns no records the wholes statement is executed for `12` seconds.

The `FUNCTION F1` execution time (alone) is `4` seconds.
If I leave joined only `FUNCTION F1` and the tables the exectuin time is again `4` seconds.

So, the SQL Server is exectuing the rest of the functions which increase the execution time of the statement.

Why SQL Server is not skipping the execution since there is `INNER JOIN` clause and the first function returns nothing?Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL engine clearly needs to evaluate the functions in order to start executing the query.  I would be surprised if there were a way to delay this.

One option is to do the checks before running the query:

```
select *
into #f1
from function f1;

if not exists (select 1 from #f1)
begin
    -- stop processing here
end;

select *
into #f2
from function f2;

if not exists (select 1 from #f2)
begin
    -- stop processing here
end;

select *
into #f3
from function f3;

if not exists (select 1 from #f3)
begin
    -- stop processing here
end;

. . .

FUNCTION #F1
INNER JOIN TABLE T1
INNER JOIN #F2 
INNER JOIN #F3
INNER JOIN #F4
...
INNER JOIN TABLE T2
```

This requires multiple statements, but might fit very well if the query is already inside a stored procedure.